# MYSQL: List all column names where their values = "Yes"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like so:

```
User_Id    Column1    Column2    Column3
1          Yes         No         Yes
2
```

I want to use mysql query to list all the column names (there are more than 3) which match the User_Id '1' and have a value of 'Yes'.

I get an error:

```
Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
<?php $myStats = $mysqli->query("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM user_services.columns WHERE myColumn = 'Yes'");
    if ($myStats->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $myStats->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row; }

    return $rows; ?>
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `CONCAT_WS` function comes in handy here:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', IF(Column1='Yes', 'Column1', NULL),
                      IF(Column2='Yes', 'Column2', NULL),
                      IF(Column3='Yes', 'Column3', NULL)) AS columns
FROM user_services.columns
WHERE User_Id = 1;
```

If you have more than 3 columns, then you may add more terms to above `CONCAT_WS` call.  Your problem mainly seems to be a SQL one, so I won't add any PHP code.

Note that your design might be better off if your column strings were spread across rows, rather than columns.  For instance, consider the following alternative:

```
User_Id | number | val
1       | 1      | Yes
1       | 2      | No
1       | 3      | Yes
```

Then, if you wanted all column numbers which were yes for user 1, you could simply do:

```
SELECT
    User_Id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(number ORDER BY number) columns
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    User_Id = 1
GROUP BY
    User_Id;
```

Comment: thanks but I not sure my code here is correct 'if ($myStats->num_rows > 0) {' as I still get the same error message as before. Any ideas?

Comment: @MikeHenry I see nothing wrong with either of my queries, but your PHP code likely has problems.  You can't just select a column's name like that.